# How to specify car destination behind some event (e.g Button Press) in AnyLogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am trying to route all cars to the nearest exits in the road network by pressing a button for starting emergency evacuation. But AnyLogic gives error that

Exception during discrete event execution
root.carMoveToSEECS_P1: 
Destination road is not specified

What is the way to dynamically change the destination road in the carMoveTo block of the Road Traffic Library of the AnyLogic.

I have tried to set the movesto and destination variables of the CarMoveTo. But it doesn't seems to work.

```
carMoveToSEECS_P1.set_movesTo(carMoveToGate1.movesTo);
carMoveToSEECS_P1.set_destination(carMoveToGate1.destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

Break your "carMoveTo" into several steps by adding a decide block and looping back.  You could have a global variable for emergency evacuation.  The carMoveTo would move the cars to individual stop lines just before exits.  If the emergency Boolean is true, then you would set the car's destination to the next exit via the carMoveTo block.  Otherwise, the car would route to the next stop line along its route.

The key will be setting up a variable structure that knows all the stop lines along a car's route.  If the road network is complex, you could run a pre-processor to let each car go to/from every source destination and build up a list of stop lines that represent the intermediate evaluation points.

Comment: Can't we just write a code to change the destination of the carMoveTo block behind an Evacuation Button and it just routes it way to that new destination as it does for the initial one?

Comment: If it is not in the API documentation, I would assume not.  There is a TON of behind the scenes logic to manage routing and collision avoidance.  I would imagine changing destinations on the fly could cause some issues.  You could always ask support.